# external js functions not being called when previewing local page in browser

Tags: javascript, css, local, transition

When I include separate js files in my webpage, the functions are not called when previewing the local page in my browser.

I'm trying to implement these page transitions.
http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/

I put the supporting files in the right place, and included them correctly in the head section of my page. I'm pretty sure of that because the css is working fine. Only the js is not.

I dont think I should need something like WAMP server right? Because its only js. The inline js in the same page is also working fine...

When I click my link, it does open the next page, but without transition. Also it adds "Error:0" at the top of the page.

What can I do to get these transitions working?

EDIT

My code looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<link href="css/transition.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fasw.transitions.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a transt="flip" href="page2.html">Next</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I removed everything else from the page and still getting the same error. I view it in Chrome and Firefox, and get the same error in both.

Comment: Please show the markup for how you include the JS files.

Comment: Is it running on a ht tp://localhost or in a file:///some-directory on your computer or is it on a test server? What Browser are you using? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @nnnnnn, I edited the question to include my code.

Comment: @edgarator, I tried it in both chrome and firefox, on both localhost and another directory. Still got the same error every time.

Comment: Have you checked permissions set on the file?

Comment: @edgarator, Ok, how would I check that? Should I be looking for something within the code/comments of the actual js and css? Because, on the creator's website I linked to above, he explains it should work after simply referencing the files and adding a single css attribute inline. Also, other commentors on the site seem to have it running smoothly.

Comment: @Dingredient Depending on your system settings, and especially if you have it running on a local or remote server you are looking at flagging the file as readable and executable by the server-process' owner. [Change permissions in Windows](http://www.mcmcse.com/microsoft/guides/ntfs_and_share_permissions.shtml) / [Change permissions in Unix](http://kb.iu.edu/data/abdb.html)... I think you need to edit your question and provide more information about where the folder structure, permissions, environment (like server or file system), etc... otherwise it's going to be hard to tackle.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if it is happening because of any js conflicts. You can check it by removing the other js files that is included in the web page.

Comment: I removed all the other js, and still get the same error. I edited the question, to show my entire code.

Comment: can you please check if it is working in any of the browsers like Google chrome?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it in Chrome and Firefox. Both show the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you are referencing the Javascript files correctly from your HTML page. Try adding an alert statement to the top of the file, and reload the page - if you don't see the alert, then you're not referencing the file correctly.

```
alert("Hello.");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what that should look like in my html? Would I use an onload function for that?